# Как отключить EventListener, после того как значение равно 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

Делаю небольшой учебный проект, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не знаю как убрать EvenListener после того как значение достигло 0, как это можно оптимально сделать?

```js
let monster = document.getElementById("monster");
let healthBarValue = document.querySelector(".health-bar-value");
let waveNumber = document.getElementById("wave-number");
let waveValue = waveNumber.textContent;

let damage = "";

function waves() {
  if (waveValue == 1) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 100;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 2) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 250;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 3) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 500;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 4) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 1000;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 5) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 1500;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 6) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 2000;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 7) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 2500;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 8) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 3000;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 9) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 4000;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == 10) {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 8000;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }

  if (waveValue == "MEGA-BOSS") {
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = 16000;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  }
}

waves();

monster.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  damage = 10;
  let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
  healthBarValue.innerHTML = health - damage;

  if (healthBarValue.textContent == 0) {
    monster.innerHTML = "YOU WIN";
    monster.removeEventListener("click", e);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@700&display=swap');

*,*::after,*::before{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(255, 223, 40);
    background-image: url(image/Balls2.png);
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;

}

.header{
    font-size: clamp(40px,3.6458333333333335vw,100px);
    margin-top: 10px;
    user-select: none;
    margin: auto;
}

.monster{
    font-size: clamp(120px,11.458333333333334vw,320px);
    margin-top: clamp(100px,11.625vw,500px);
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.health-bar{
    width: clamp(300px,31.25vw,900px);
    height: clamp(40px,2.6041666666666665vw,70px);
    margin-top: clamp(20px,2.0833333333333335vw,60px);
    border: 5px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.next{
    margin-top: clamp(30px,2.6041666666666665vw,70px);
    width: clamp(300px,21.875vw,740px);
    height: clamp(40px,3.125vw,80px);
    background-color: blueviolet;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    transition: 0.2s;
    font-size: clamp(20px,2.0833333333333335vw,60px);
}

.wave{
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: clamp(20px,2.0833333333333335vw,60px);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    user-select: none;
}

.next:hover, .shop:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}

.upper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.shop{
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: clamp(70px,8.25vw,170px);
    height: 60px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.money{
    user-select: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.health-bar-fill{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgb(255, 75, 75);
transition: width 0.5s;
}

.health-bar-value{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <title>Kill Mob</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="upper">
        <button class="shop">Shop</button>
        <h1 class="header">KILL IT!</h1>
        <p class="money">Money:000</p>
      </div>
      <h2 class="wave">WAVE: <span id="wave-number">1</span></h2>
      <div id="monster" class="monster"></div>
      <div class="health-bar">
        <div class="health-bar-value">1K</div>
        <div class="health-bar-fill"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А в чем смысл `let health = `? Если оно нигде не используется и объявлено только внутри `if`?

Comment: У вас есть два варианта. В первом вы носите callback функцию для addEventListener в отдельную функцию и используете ее. Тогда вы сможете удалять указав это имя функции. Второй вариант, вы можете проверить значение хп и в зависимости от значения, сделать return, дабы действия не продолжались.

Comment: Насчет функции `waves`, попробуйте ее переписать используя объект для волна: значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если немного оптимизировать код, не идельно, но все же, то должно получиться что-то такое. Некоторые моменты я пояснил в комментариях, но если будут вопросы, задавайте.

```
let monster = document.getElementById("monster");
let healthBarValue = document.querySelector(".health-bar-value");
let waveNumber = document.getElementById("wave-number");
let waveValue = waveNumber.textContent;

let damage = 10;

function removeMonsterClickHandler() { // функция, которая убирает EventListener с обрабочиком monsterClickHandler
   monster.removeEventListener("click", monsterClickHandler, true);
}
function monsterClickHandler(e) { // создадим отельно обработчик клика
  this.health-= damage; // this - это monster
  healthBarValue.innerHTML = this.health;

  if (this.health <= 0) { // Вдруг damage будет больше, чем оствшееся хп
    this.innerHTML = "YOU WIN";
    removeMonsterClickHandler(); // Убираем EventListener
  }
}

/**
* Объект с волнами
* Ключ - номер волны
* Значение - здоровье монстра
*/
const wavesMap = {
  1: 100,
  2: 250,
  3: 500,
  4: 1000,
  5: 1500,
  6: 2000,
  7: 2500,
  8: 3000,
  9: 4000,
  10: 8000,
  'MEGA-BOSS': 16000,
}

function waves() {
 for (let wave in wavesMap) { // Перебираем объект с волнами в цикле
   if (waveValue !== wave) continue; // Если ключ не равен номеру текущей волны, идем дальше
   monster.health = wavesMap[wave]; // дадим монстру свойство health для удобства
   healthBarValue.innerHTML = monster.health; // покажем health мостра в хелсбаре
   break; // Выходим из цикла
 }
}

waves();

monster.addEventListener("click", monsterClickHandler, true);
```

- Тут можно почитать [про циклы](https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for). Чтобы не было такого нагромождения ветвлений с `if`. Так же полезно почитать про [конструкцию switch](https://learn.javascript.ru/switch) по той же причине.
- Тут конкретно [про for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Если не понятно, что такое `this` в функции `monsterClickHandler()` и откуда оно взялось, то - это свойство контекста, являющееся ссылкой на объект, в нашем случае `monster`. Можете почитать о контексте и `this` на [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods).

#### UPD

Мне нечего было делать и я тут накатал свою версию вашего кликера. HTML и CSS почти не менял, хотя хотел. Там все уровни, покупки апгрейдов нет, поэтому показатель урона всегда равен 10, но я надеюсь, вы с этим разберетесь сами. После победы над боссом игра начнется с начала без сброса заработанных очков, типа NG+. Сделал рабочими хелсбар, очки, анимации ударов и смерти врага.

Забирайте, разбирайте:
[Исходник на CodePen](https://codepen.io/neverm1ndo/pen/wvmwZLO?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста!

```js
monster.addEventListener("click", fight);

function fight(e) {
    damage = 10;
    let health = healthBarValue.textContent;
    healthBarValue.innerHTML = health - damage;
    if (healthBarValue.textContent == 0) {
        EndGame();
    }
};

function EndGame() {
    monster.innerHTML = "YOU WIN";
    monster.removeEventListener("click", fight);
}
```

Comment: В ваш ответ следует включить больше подробностей для более понятного понимая того что именно делает ваш код, ответ вопрос отредактировать кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1424503/edit).